# how to use spring-mvc for getting particular screen resolutions for mobile devices?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When users hit on the my web page i want them to provide content according to the screen size.

e.g if user want to download wallpaper then i want to provide that wallpaper according to the user's mobile device screen resolution

Is there any way to get screen resolution of all mobile devices in `spring-mvc`?

Comment: The solution that comes to my mind is to use javascript on the front-end side, that will detect the resolution, and then return it to back-end via ajax, so the user won't notice. 

I don't think that HTTP requests got that information about exact size of  user screen. 
And in Spring-Mobile there is LiteDeviceResolver, which also won't give You exact screen size.

Comment: You can use [`spring-mobile`](http://projects.spring.io/spring-mobile/) to get integration with mobile devices. Or simply use css for different screen sizes (basically this is also what Bootstrap does).

Comment: @patrykos91-i have already used js for getting screen size but that code doesnt always works on some browsers..

Comment: @M. Deinum- spring mobile just give an idea about user is using mobile device or teblet..but i want to get the particular screen resolution

Comment: Then just use CSS with breakpoints for different screen resolutions.